# How to simplify composite type in variable

Tags: c++11

I'm looping through some input and output strings for a unit test, and my first attempt was:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> pairs {{"input1", "output1"}, {"input2", "output2"}};
```

As you can see it's quite verbose. I've tried to use `auto`, but g++ complains about the nested init lists.

How can this be simplified?

I realize this might not be the recommended data structure for the job (you could use a `std::map` for instance) I'm asking this out of pure curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `make_xxx` functions: their purpose is creating containers/wrappers by deducing their item type from the passed arguments.

You will have to create your `make_vector` function. Here's [a possible implementation (C++14)](https://github.com/SuperV1234/cppcon2015/blob/master/1_ForArgs%2Fp2.cpp).

```
auto pairs = make_vector(
    std::make_pair("input1", "output1"), 
    std::make_pair("input2", "output2")
)
```

---

Alternatively, you can simply use `using` to make the code more readable:

```
using str_pair = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;
using vec_of_str_pair = std::vector<str_pair>;

vec_of_str_pair pairs {{"input1", "output1"}, {"input2", "output2"}};
```

---

This problem is likely to be solved with [this proposal (N4471)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4471.html), which allows template deduction in constructors.

It will allow you to say something similar to `std::vector<auto> v = ...` or `std::pair<auto> p = ...`, which will deduce the template parameter from the container's constructor.

Comment: Unbelievable, I just listened the CppCast that featured you, like 1h ago! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @elnigno: if you are satisfied, do you mind accepting this answer so that the question can be marked as "solved"? Thanks.